# can safearrays be passed across process boundaries through com objects?

Tags: com, safearray

can safearrays be passed across process boundaries through com objects ?

Comment: COM is not the most efficient data transport so if you want to pass large amount of data in an awway you may want to find alternative transport methods.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have control over it, I am using data from a 3rd party activex control...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you registered the marshaller for the interface, yeah, no problem.  The std marshaller can do it.

Comment: What do you mean by "std marshaller"? The Automation marshaller or something else?

Comment: Can I register the automation marshaller using CoMarshalInterface http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms678428(VS.85).aspx from the client side ?

Comment: No, that's what you *use* to marshal an interface.  The marshaller is registered by setting the HKCR\Interface\{iid}\ProxyStubClsid32 registry key.  The CLSID for the std marshaller is {00020424-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}.  Have a look-see with Regedit.exe